# Formatar dados antes de salvar no banco

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5

Estou utilizando o `Laravel` para desenvolver um sistema, porém estou com um problema nos dados vindo de um formulário, preciso formatar uma dado no seguinte formato (***#.##***) para realizar determinados cálculos, o problema que o valor vem com o seguinte formato (***###.#***) fazendo o valor final sair errado, não sei como eu posso formatar esse dado no `Controller` ou antes de fazer o envio dele.

Segue o código do input

```
<label for="peso">Peso (Kg) : </label>
<input type="text" name="peso" class="form-control" v-model="peso"/>
<label for="altura">Altura (m) : </label>
<input type="text" name="altura" class="form-control" v-model="altura" v-mask="'#.##'"/>
<br/>
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-success pull-right"/>
<br>
```

Segue o código do Controller onde eu preciso validar os dados

```
public function store(ImcRequest $request)
{
    $imc = new Imc;
    $imc->peso = $request->peso;
    $imc->altura = $request->altura;
    $altura2 = ($imc->altura) * ($imc->altura);
    $imc->imccalculado = ($imc->peso / $altura2);

    if (($imc->imccalculado) < 16.00) {
        $imc->classificacao = 'Magreza severa';
    } elseif (($imc->imccalculado >= 16.00) && ($imc->imccalculado <= 16.99)) {
        $imc->classificacao = 'Magreza moderada';
    } elseif (($imc->imccalculado >= 17.00) && ($imc->imccalculado <= 18.40)) {
        $imc->classificacao = 'Magreza leve';
    } elseif (($imc->imccalculado >= 18.5) && ($imc->imccalculado <= 24.99)) {
        $imc->classificacao = 'Normal';
    } elseif (($imc->imccalculado >= 25.00) && ($imc->imccalculado <= 29.99)) {
        $imc->classificacao = 'Preobeso';
    } elseif (($imc->imccalculado >= 30.00) && ($imc->imccalculado <= 34.99)) {
        $imc->classificacao = 'Obesidade leve';
    } elseif (($imc->imccalculado >= 35.00) && ($imc->imccalculado <= 39.99)) {
        $imc->classificacao = 'Obesidade media';
    } elseif (($imc->imccalculado) >= 40.00) {
        $imc->classificacao = 'Obesidade morbida';
    }

    $imc->user_id = Auth::id();
    $imc->save();

    return redirect('/imcs');
}
```

Comment: De onde vem as informações? do banco de dados? você pode alterar a mascara no banco, não seria o caso?

Comment: As informações o usuário informa em um formulário, antes de salvar no banco eu realizo um calculo, pelo valor vim com o formato errado no formulário ele acaba salvando errado no banco.

Comment: Como está definido o migrations do `User` ? Em qualquer caso você pode adicionar ao model do `User` uma função assessora para obter o campo formatado da forma que pretende.

Comment: E como eu faria isso no model? Sou novo no Laravel.

Comment: Guilherme você está enviando isso com Ajax? pelo Angular ? e o formato seria na v-model Altura? tem como dizer como você está enviando e isso constar na sua pergunta!

Comment: Estou submetendo o formulário pelo método POST, o v-model foi um teste que fiz e não funcionou, estou usando vue para exibir os dados do usuário, mas isso é feito somente após o cálculo ser efetuado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta usar:

```
$imc->peso = number_format($request->peso, 2, '.');
$imc->altura = number_format($request->altura, 2, '.');
```

Outra opção de gambiarra:

```
$num = 100.4;
$num = str_replace('.', '', $num);
$num = str_replace(',', '', $num);
echo substr($num, 0, strlen($num)-2).".".substr($num, strlen($num)-2);
```

Acredito ser melhor tratar números de 3 dígitos com uma mensagem de erro ou mascara no formulário, mas esses são exemplos de gambiarras pra tratamento no `controller`. Uma dica, verifique como os dados chegam no `controller` antes, coloque um `dd($request->campoX);` no inicio do código da função pois o problema pode estar em algum componente carregado no JS da pagina também.